# Generar un codigo automatico en base a 2 campos

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando hacer que me genere un codigo automatico en un formulario, tengo el siguiente formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la base de donde tomo esos 2 campos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del formulario

```
<form action="save_adm.php" method="POST">
                                           


                    <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zona</label>
                                           <div class="col-sm-8">
                                           <select name="zona_name" id="zona_name" class="form-control">
                             <option value="0">Seleccione Zona</option>
                             <?php while($row = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) 
                                           { ?>
                               <option value="<?php echo $row['zona_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['zona_name']; ?></option>
                             <?php } 
                                           ?>
                           </select>
                                           </div>
                                           </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sector</label>
                                           <div class="col-sm-8">
                                           <select name="sector_name" id="sector_name" class="form-control">
                             <option value="0">Seleccione Sector</option>
                             <?php while($row = $resultado3->fetch_assoc()) 
                                           { ?>
                               <option value="<?php echo $row['sector_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sector_name']; ?></option>
                             <?php } 
                                           ?>
                           </select>
                                           </div>
                                           </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo </label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>

                                           
           
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
<input type="submit" name="save" Value="Registro" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>


                                       </form>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que en el campo Sector me genere un codigo automatico en base al llenado de los 2 campos anteriores, por ejemplo al seleccionar el campo " Zona 1 " tiene el codigo 01, al seleccionar el campo " Sector 1 " tiene el codigo 01, quiero que en el tercer campo el codigo me quede asi:

**01-01-01**

el primer 01 es de la zona
el segundo 01 es del sector
el tercer 01 es el codido automatico y que se vaya incrementando o validando si no existe en alguna tabla, ya que no se como hacer eso

Comment: Podrías hacer eso directamente en la base de datos, mediante un trigger en MySql, usando un trigger BEFORE_INSERT

Comment: perdona pero soy algo nuevo y nunca he usado triggers